# Mongodb: Document size of 29344731 is larger than maximum of 16777216

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

When we are upgrading AEM 6.1 instance with mongo (Mongo version: 2.6 ) to AEM 6.3  with mongo (Mongo version: 3.2) we are facing the exception.

> org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.document.DocumentNodeStore
>   Background operation failed: org.bson.BsonSerializationException:
>   Document size of 29344731 is larger than maximum of 16777216.

How DocumentNodestore exceeds its limit? 
Is there anyway to resolve the issue?
Is revision garbage collection will reduce the DocumentNodeStore size?

Comment: As per MongoDB documentation the maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes. If you want to store more than 16 MB size of document in MongoDB. Then use the GridFS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per `MongoDB BOL` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) The maximum BSON document size is **`16`** megabytes.

The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of `RAM` or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, `MongoDB` provides the **`GridFS API`**.

`GridFS` is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of `16 MB`.

For your further ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667597/understanding-mongodb-bson-document-size-limit/19401813)

Comment: I'm a new user. No matter how you wrap it, this s*cks.

Comment: What's worse--Mongo lets you write huge documents but not read them back into RAM

Comment: @duhaime - do you have a reference for that? It would explain the error I'm encountering, but seems ridiculous they would enforce that on read rather than on write!

Comment: @Kyrstellaine I don't have a reference but it should be easy enough to write a ~1GB document then query for it. If the write succeeds but the read fails you have your answer!